# Multiplayer game architecture, should clients also maintain a Players list locally?

Tags: architecture, client-server

I am creating a multiplayer game and was wondering if only the server knows about the actual players in the game, or is this list sent to the clients too?

So for example the server knows about each Player's ID and NickName, in a list.
Should clients also receive this list?

Some potential use cases for this would be:

- Scoreboards(server only sends a player ID and a score instead of id,nickname and score)
- Sorting teams, server tells client which player ids are his teammates, doesnt need to send id and nickname because clients already have the players info locally

Comment: It depends on whether the client needs it or not. As long as you don't send sensible information to the clients, if it has use cases for it, then sure, send it along.

Comment: Well, if you want to show player nicknames, avatars and such, you have to send that information over. And depending on how complex the game is and how frequent the updates are, you might have to hold much more information than that on the client. E.g., something like a card game might only need just enough data to reconstruct the current state of the table, while something like Counter Strike will run the simulation of the entire game world on the client too, as well as on the server, in order to combat lag, and back-correct any mispredictions.

Comment: A "misprediction" being something like: I thought the enemy player missed you, but nope, server says you're dead. When this happens, the interval is usually so short that it isn't very obvious, but it becomes apparent on a bad connection. If you're interested, search for "netcode" and "how netcode works" and variations of that.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should provide the client only with the minimal information it needs to do its job.
In a multiplayer game that'd be people in the current instance (and maybe not even all of those if some can't be interacted with for example).
If the server maintains high score lists, those can contain the names of players of course, and those should then be sent at such a time as the client requests the list but no sooner.

Similarly, the client should not retain such information that isn't needed for its proper functioning at any moment (let's ignore caching here for now).
So if the client has no more need for another player's information, it will be removed from memory.

As to WHAT player information to send to the client: send the absolute minimum only. This would often be only the display name (NOT the account name) and whatever information is needed to render the player's character on screen. Definitely never send email addresses, usernames, passwords, payment information, and other privacy sensitive information (this should be obvious but I've seen applications that make such mistakes more often than is healthy).

ONLY cache such information on the client as would cause serious performance problems and/or network congestion if it has to be retransmitted to the client regularly. This is mainly for security and privacy reasons, but a good practice to observe overall as it tends to make prevention of stale caches easier (you don't want the client and server to get out of synch with such data after all).

Answer (score 0):

While you might well *cache* such information locally, your server would of course be the only authority.  Therefore, there is a **design tradeoff** which revolves around the need to balance "request load against the server" against your need for this list of information.

***Only you*** can make this **design decision** for **your** situation. There is no "categorical" answer. Which is why this question will very soon be "voted off the island."